# How to Duplicate an Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a Blackjack simulator. I have the following string array called `deck` (I prefer to use an array over an enum):

```cs
string[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A", };
```

User will enter the deck number with Input Dialog:

```cs
byte deckNumber;
deckNumber = Convert.ToByte(Interaction.InputBox("Enter The Deck Number", "Deck Number", "3", 10, 10));
```

How can I duplicate the array with `deckNumber`? For example user enter `2`, array will be:

```
{ "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A" };
```

I think I need a for loop but I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: Actually, a deck is a group of 52 cards.. not just 13 cards...

Comment: well writing here 52cards does not make sense :(

Comment: You're not serious, are you ? 
do you plan to write a software with only 13 cards out of the 52 ???

then, when you use twice, you don't want the first 3 to be different than the second 3 :??? they are all the same ?? just 3's ???

Comment: i will multiply it with 4 too if I find to way to duplicate it

Comment: @mlwn Please don't say you would write it with 52 elements.

Comment: @L.B, the four 2's are not the same .. you have four types of cards.. spades, club, blablabla.. i don't even know the names or colors...

Comment: @mlwn I don't need them in this project. thanks for advice

Comment: @mlwn In fact, There are two colors Black and Red :)

Comment: @poster... please consider using the deck as a range 0 to 51... `range(52)` .. that would help you.. trust me...

Comment: @L.B, I like the color stufff.. and upvoted.. hehehee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A", };
var newDeck = Enumerable.Repeat(deck, 2).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or later, you can use LINQ as L.B. has shown:

```
var newDeck = Enumerable.Repeat(deck, 2).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

`Enumerable.Repeat(deck, 2)` gives you two elements that are each a `string[]`,  `.SelectMany(x => x)` flattens this into one series of strings, and `.ToArray()` obviously converts the series into an array.

Otherwise, you can use a loop:

```
var newDeck = new string[deck.Length * deckNumber];

for (int d = 0; d < deckNumber; d++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
    {
        newDeck[d * deck.Length + i] = deck[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var source = new string[]{"a","b"};

var copy = new List(source).ToArray();